# Correct way to say “life is a lesson, you learn it when you are through”

Tags: translation, word-choice, phrases, song-lyrics

In Limp Biskit’s “Take a Look Around” they use this phrase I find pretty cool. “Life is a lesson, you learn it when you are through”. So basically the lesson never ends, until you die.

I’ve been meaning to come with a good translation, a brief formal one preferably. These are some options I think might be acceptable but not sure. What do you think? Which of these are correct? Which or what would be a good way? What would be more formal / polite options?

1) 人生は教訓。終わったら学ぶ。
2) 人生は教訓。終わりに学ぶ。
3) 人生は教訓。あなたはそれは終わったら学ぶ。
4) 人生は教訓。それは終わるまで学べない。
5) 人生は教訓。それは終わるまで学べられない。
6) 人生は教訓です。それは終わるまで学べないもの
7) 人生は人生終わった時まで学べない教訓です
8) 人生は終わった時まで学べない教訓です

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The literal translation is "人生はレッスン, 終わった時にそれを学ぶ". It is difficult to translate "Lesson" in "Life is a lesson" into an appropriate Japanese word.

I think 教訓 is not appropriate for the phrase. There are many more natural ways of saying the phrase and I think 人生死ぬまで勉強 is best and the most common way of saying it.

Comment: Thank you Yuuichi but isn’t 勉強 to study rather than learn? I don’t think this phrase implies some active study of life. Could you please explain some more?

Comment: "The lesson never ends, until you die" is translated as 人生のレッスン(教え, 授業)は、死ぬまで終わらない. It means "You keep studying the lesson until you die". It is translated as "人生死ぬまで勉強", which is often used as the meaning of the phrase

Comment: Thank you very much Yuuichi. A known formal, polite and brief phrase indeed has to be the right answer. Thanks! Now I wonder what a spicy and sarcastic version like the song’s would be like... (^-^)

Comment: Yes, the most common way of saying the phrase is my answer. However, there are many ways of saying it. My ideas of a spicy and sarcastic version are 人生なんて死ぬまでわからねえよ and 人生はレッスン、死ぬまで終わらない. It is difficult to translate "Lesson" in "Life is a lesson" into an appropriate Japanese word.